# Is there a way to Collect Lat-Long in a Google Docs Form?

Tags: google-maps-api, google-fusion-tables, google-docs, google-forms

I'm helping out a small non profit. They are collecting some simple data using a [Google Docs Form](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/87809?hl=en). The need to collect exact latlong (upto 5 meters accuracy is fine).

Ideally the end user would click on a map and that lat-long would be submitted along with the rest of the form.

I have seen the mapbox blog talk about this [here](http://www.mapbox.com/blog/2012-09-05-mapping-crowdsourced-locations-google-docs/). But that is using the mapbox API.

I was wondering if there exists a ready made [template](https://drive.google.com/templates?type=forms&pli=1#) to collect the point on top of Google Maps. I don't want to spend half a day converting the mapbox sample to Google Maps API, and then find out that something already existed.

So Is anyone aware of template where a point was collected from Google Maps in Google Forms?

Answer (score 1):

If Google docs is using googles web Mercator projection and accuracy in the range of +-5m is needed you should read this to understand this aspect of your challenge.

https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/the-google-maps-bing-maps-spherical-mercator-projection/

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about Google maps but you might try something like [itouchmap.com](http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html)  or [mapcoordinates.net](http://www.mapcoordinates.net/en). Also Excel has a mapping plug-in.  I haven't used it for quite a while but I think you can get coordinates outputted to a spread sheet.  Search for "Excel Power Map"